# Java Mongo: How to get the max of each docuemnt

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with complex document, each with user Id. each userId has timestamp, so I'd like to return document for all users in organization, with the latest timestamp per each user.

This is what I tried, it sort of worked, except only the timestamp & userId fields were mapped in the result - all other data wasn't transferred:

```
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("organization").is("someOrg");

    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(criteria),
            group("userId").last("timestamp").as("timestamp")
    );

    AggregationResults<UserPerformanceAlert> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, collectionName, UserPerformanceAlert.class);
```

I tried project but it kept giving me exceptions saying  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExposedFields must not be null!"

Note: the full document has complex inner objects that I need to retrieve. normal find() method works just find to serialize the data to my class model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found the issue, I had to specify all the fields at the group() part:

```
group("userId", "type", "header", "body", "scopes", "accountId").last("timestamp").as("timestamp")
```